# Is there a way to get the share count of discussions in community salesforce?

Tags: community, chatter, feeditem

I'm working on a component and need assistance with retrieving the share count of a FeedItem using Apex.

I have explored the Salesforce documentation and resources but haven't been able to find a straightforward solution.

I understand that the FeedItem object stores information about Chatter posts and discussions, but I'm unsure about the specific approach to retrieve the share count.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to retrieve the share count of a FeedItem in Salesforce using Apex? Any sample code or query examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!