# How can I get the view count of the discussions(Feed Item) in apex in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, feeditem

I am building a custom component where I want to show discussions with the number of views on it. I checked the feeditem object but there is no field for view count. Is there some other object which stores the view count of feeditem or is there a way of getting the view count via api in apex?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get the share count of discussions in community salesforce?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/406850/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-share-count-of-discussions-in-community-salesforce)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View Count For FeedItem](https://www.scribd.com/document/441055630/View-Count-For-FeedItem#)

Answer (score 0):

```
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getReadByForFeedElement(communityId, feedElementId);
```

You can specify Experience Cloud site, internal, or null for the communityId.
Naturally the feedElementId is the item Id. This does not return instances of it being seen aka it won't return 10 if one user has seen it 10 times it will only return how many users have seen it (and who they are).